# Username & Password issues: Input recognition - Java

Tags: java, passwords, account

I wrote a simple little program to ask for a user ID, a Username, and a password. So far, I have the user ID working but the Username doesn't work. I think it has something to do with comparing Strings, but alas, I do not know.

Most of the important code is located in login.class. I am using Account objects stored in an array where the user inputs an ID and the account stored at the place equal to the id (for instace Accounts[4] would be an account, Derp, and the user access it by entering in the ID of 4) then inputs a username, and then a password. I do not wish to refine the program further than becoming operational, but advice is always welcome.

```
public class Login {

static boolean IDisOK = false;
static boolean usernameisOK = false;
static boolean passwordisOK = false;

static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

static Account test = new Account("guest", "blank", 0);
static Account[] accounts = new Account[1];

static int tmpID = -1;
static String tmpUsername = "has not been entered, weird";
static String tmpPassword = "has not been entered, weird";
static Account tmp;

public static void initAccounts() {
    accounts[0] = test;
}

public static void getaccID() { // Prompts and asks the user for and ID
    System.out.println("Please enter in your account ID");
    tmpID = input.nextInt();
    if (tmpID < accounts.length) {
        IDisOK = true;
    }//end of if statement

}//end of getaccID

public static void getaccUsername() { // Prompts and asks user for a username if      the ID was OK
    if (IDisOK == true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the username linked to the ID: " + tmpID);
    tmpUsername = input2.nextLine();
    if (accounts[tmpID].username == tmpUsername) {
        usernameisOK = true;
        }//end of if statement
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please get a valid ID then come back.");
        System.exit(0);//end of if statement

    }
}//end of getaccUsername

public static void getaccPassword() { //Prompts and asks user for a password is the     username was OK
    System.out.println("Please enter the password set for this username: " +     accounts[tmpID].username);
    tmpPassword = input.nextLine();
    if (usernameisOK == true) {
        if (accounts[tmpID].password == tmpPassword) {
            passwordisOK = true;
            Main.setAuth(true);
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Please come back when you have a valid     username.");
        System.exit(0);

    }
}//end of getaccPassword

public static void signIn() {
    initAccounts();
    getaccID();
    getaccUsername();
    getaccPassword();



}//end of signIn method

}//end of class



public class Account {

String username = " ";
String password = " ";
int ID;



public Account(String userIn, String passwordIn, int idIn) {
    this.username = userIn;
    this.password = passwordIn;
    this.ID = idIn;
}//end of constructor



public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}
public int getID() {
    return this.ID;
}
public void setUsername(String input) {
    username = input;
}
public void setPassword(String input) {
    password = input;
}

}

public class Main {

static boolean hasbeensaved = false;
static boolean auth = false;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Login.signIn();
    if (getAuth() == true) {





    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are comparing if the memory address of the references are the same

```
 if (accounts[tmpID].username == tmpUsername)
```

should be

```
if (accounts[tmpID].username.equals(tmpUsername))
```

Just as a note, everything in Java is a reference, except the primitive data types. So if you're comparing object values, you must EVER implement the equals method...

Comment: Haha! Thanks so much! It was a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

Another classic == and .equals() miss interpretation example

== compares to see if the 2 reference variables are pointing to the same object, where as in here we want the compare if the 2 string objects have same state, hence use .equals() which returns a boolean true if both String objects have same state, else return false.

try this:

```
public static void getaccUsername() { // Prompts and asks user for a username if          the ID was OK
    if (IDisOK == true) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the username linked to the ID: " + tmpID);
    tmpUsername = input2.nextLine();
    if (accounts[tmpID].username.equals( tmpUsername)) {// use .equals in string state comparision
        usernameisOK = true;
        }//end of if statement
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please get a valid ID then come back.");
        System.exit(0);//end of if statement

    }
}//end of getaccUsername
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, it was quite useful.